# Nexus 7 stuck on google's logo after flashed the building of AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, nexus-7

This is my first time to flash the AOSP building on the device. I just followed the google's instructions to download and build the Android source code. Since I have a Nexus 7 (2013), so I chose the target to "aosp_flo-userdebug" before starting to build. Then I ran "make" to build, and the building was successful.

After that I rebooted the device and went into the boot loader, flashed the device by command:

```
$ fastboot -w flashall
```

The flash succeed. Then after the device rebooted, it just stuck on the Google's logo screen and never continue. If I flash it back to the factory image, it can continue starting. So I think maybe there are some mistakes during the building or flashing that causes the problem. But I don't know how to find the problem.

I also tried to flash only system.img by:

```
$ fastboot flash system system.img
```

But it's till the same result. Hope someone can give me some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: you will probably have better luck on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, I was lucky at there. I resolved my problem eventually. In short, just because I missed the device specific binaries during the building. Here's the link http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129817/nexus-7-stuck-on-googles-logo-after-flashed-the-building-of-aosp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem eventually. In short, just because I missed the device specific binaries during the building.